# Source of QGIS (3.x) Processing Tools

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3, qgis-3

Is it possible to access the Python source code of the processing tools in QGIS 3.x (for example the Package layer tool) or is there a central code repository available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For all available processing tools:

  https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins/processing/algs

---

- For the *Package layers* tool:

  https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/4b411e0d1af887a0abba4030899a219d6d07317d/src/analysis/processing/qgsalgorithmpackage.cpp